# "... while / when processing large volumes of data" - which is correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which one does more sense and is more natural?

> Database performance was analyzed **while / when** processing large
>   volumes of data.

What I want to say is that the database performance was measured while the database was under heavy workload (the higher workload = the higher performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be to use **while** to show the analysis occurred during the **entire duration of processing** large volumes of data.

Using **when** might mean the same, but could also mean only during the beginning of or end of the processing.

Answer (score 1):

"We tested the database's performance while processing large volumes of data, and analysed the results."

While implies that the testing was done during the entirety of the time spent processing large data volumes.

"When" can mean that, but could also be interpreted to mean either shorter durations of testing, and/or that the processing of the large volumes prompted the test (or the analysis).